# Auto-Close Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have need where I have to auto close the Alert Dialog in 2 different situations

1. Auto-close the dialog after I get a return value which I am waiting for
2. Auto-close the dialog after 10 sec of no input from User. I know I should use timer of some sort, but not sure how to attach it with dialog.

I know and understand that its not right way to handle UI, but my requirement needs me to do this.

Please share your thoughts,

Thanks,

SKU

Answer (score 4):

1- For the first case :

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this).create();
...
alertDialog.show();
int valueIamWaitingFor = 5;
if (aValue == valueIamWaitingFor){
    alertDialog.hide();
}
```

2- For the second case :

```
private static final ScheduledExecutorService executor = 
  Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
public AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this).create();
...
alertDialog.show();
Runnable hideDialog= new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       this.alertDialog.hide();
    }
};
executor.schedule(hideDialog, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Hi Zakaria... I followed what you did with Case-2. But WRT to case 1, I am waiting for return value in strings which will take mostly minimum 4 sec (from a separate thread) to max 8 sec to return. I am not sure if your code snippet for case 1 will work? Could you please explain that part?

Comment: @sku : just out of curiosity, what make you sure that the value will be returned within 8 sec max ?

Comment: Its only because of long time observation, If it is not replying with a answer within 8 sec of time... There is something wrong.

Comment: Then apply the code snippet I put in the "second case" part. Just change the "10" to "8".

Comment: @Zakaria.... My question was about Case-1. I understood your code snippet about Case-2. In case-1 the wait is for a return value, as soon as it get the return value... the dialog should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit a custom Dialog from AlertDialog, where you handle your timer in [onStart](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html). Using the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) would be good to do the countdown.

Auto-closing dialog ain't something bad... at least we always see this in changing screen resolution (win xp) which is good for such scenario. Maybe you can also include the countdown timer on the button (like "closing in 5 seconds").